# How to first step to get firestore's value finished then second step to let gotten value sent to 2nd snippet code?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager, android-mvvm

Because Firestore's .addSnapshotListener is async. How could I first step to get imgsGroupIds from firestore then second step to send imgsGroupIds into trackImageViewModel.getUserTrackedImgs(imgsGroupIds!!)?

In other words, how to let step 1 run finished then run step 2 after step 1 got imgsGroupIds?

```
runBlocking{
            val imgsGroupIds: MutableList<String>? = mutableListOf()

            val deferred = async {
                Log.d(TAG, "CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO): Thread:${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                Firebase.firestore
                    .collection("userData")
                    .document(uid!!)
                    .collection("trackGroupId")
                    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "addSnapshotListener: Thread:${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: FirebaseFirestoreException: $error")
                        querySnapshot?.forEach {
                            val imgsGroupId = it.id
                            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: imgsGroupId = $imgsGroupId")
                            imgsGroupIds!!.add(imgsGroupId)
                        }
                    }
            }
            deferred.await()

            Log.d(
                TAG,
                "trackImageViewModel.getUserTrackedImgs: Thread:${Thread.currentThread().name}"
            )
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: imgsGroupIds = $imgsGroupIds")
            if (imgsGroupIds != null) {
                trackImageViewModel.getUserTrackedImgs(imgsGroupIds)
                    .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                        tracked_imgs_recycler_view.apply {
                            setHasFixedSize(true)
                            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                            val detailRecyclerAdapter =
                                DetailRecyclerAdapter(requireContext(), it).apply {
                                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                                }
                            adapter = detailRecyclerAdapter

                        }
                    })
            }


        }
```

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value) is useful to you ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody  Thank you for reply. What you gave is a little bit complex,but I will try to study it.^^

Comment: you don't have to follow what i sent, the idea is mainly that (as you've explained) you need to execute the code as soon as the other result is available, with coroutines you might have better solutions available compared to what i've sent, i'm sure someone will be able to help you

Answer (score 3):

You can use coroutines [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html). It's in the core module.

This is the "contacts" documents in Firestore:
[Firestore collection/documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Zcz.png)

Module class Contact:

```
class Contact(var name: String) {
    constructor(): this("John Doe")
}
```

by using callbackFlow {} pre-design your Firestore read:

```
fun getContacts() = callbackFlow<Contact> {
    val ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("contacts")
    val eventListener = ref.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        if (error != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getContacts: ", error )
        } else {
            for (doc in value!!) {
                val contact = doc.toObject(Contact::class.java)
                this@callbackFlow.sendBlocking(contact)
            }
        }
    }
    awaitClose {
        eventListener.remove()
    }
}
```

Here is the data that actually read and get:

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        getContacts().collect {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ${it.name}")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very thank you,teacher Hank. Your answer is very powerful and wise.I will study your code to understand what it really mean.